# How to count the sum of amount in list by group?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Im trying to create a listview where group by label. like this 
 [VIEW IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl2kk.jpg)
and i want to get the total amount by group 
how to achieve that ?

i use GroupListView in flutter to group my list

my model in list

```
`class ExpensesModel {
    final int id;
    final String label;
    final int amount;
    final int icon;
`
```

I found this code to get the length per list but im confuse how to get the amount.

```
`Widget countTitle(String title){
       totalAmount = expensesContainer.where((ec) => ec.label == title).toList().length.toString();
       return Text(totalAmount);
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `List.map()` to iterate to all the elements of the list.Then you can check the `lebel`.If it matches then you can add its `amount` to the total.

```
Widget countTitle(String title){
       int totalAmount=0;
       expensesContainer.map((ec){
           if(ec.lebel==title)
               totalAmount+=ec.amount;
       }
       return Text(totalAmount.toString());
  }`
```